# jquery-mobile-960 fluid layout intersperses grid blocks when used inside an <li>

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery-mobile-960's fluid layout http://jeromeetienne.github.io/jquery-mobile-960/demoFluid.html.

When I use the container_12 class directly inside a page or a section, I get desired results i.e., first two grids in a single row and the second grid in the next row

---

### 1X2 grid 1X10 grid

### 1X4 grid

```
          <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_2">
              1X2 grid
            </div>
            <div class="grid_10">
              1X10 grid
            </div>
            <div class="grid_4">
              1X4 grid
            </div>
          </div>
```

But when I use the same inside a `<li>`, then the results are totally different. The third grid gets interspersed with the first two.

```
<div data-role="content" role="main">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
      <li data-icon="false">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_2">
              1X2 grid
            </div>
            <div class="grid_10">
              1X10 grid
            </div>
            <div class="grid_4">
              1X4 grid
            </div>
          </div>>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li data-icon="false"><a href="#">No icon</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I thought a `<div>` is a `<div>`, irrespective of where it is located - inside an `<li>` or otherwise.

Any thoughts around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just have an extra closing DIV and an extra angle bracket in your listview markup after the grid_4 div ( `</div>>` ). Try this:

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
  <li data-icon="false">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="container_12">
        <div class="grid_2">
          1X2 grid
        </div>
        <div class="grid_10">
          1X10 grid
        </div>
        <div class="grid_4">
          1X4 grid
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-icon="false"><a href="#">No icon</a></li>
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/bFBdp/1/)**